# How do I reference the object in a System block on Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm programmatically creating a Simulink model, and as part of the model I am creating System blocks which use a class I have created. The issue I am having is I don't know how to access these objects now, for example I can't change their properties very easily or I can't get them to execute any functions. How would I be able to do this ?

Thanks in advance,

Edo

I have tried using the set_param function, however I do not want to change the parameter into a value but another object, or array of objects, which set_param does not work with.